# Vue.js + Bootstrap - question - invoking $bvToast from store.js

Tags: vue.js

I have probably very profoundly simple question: how to invoke methods located in components from store.js, for instance I want a toast popup from store mutation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The $bvToast can be found in BToast export. You can import it to use it.

```
import { BToast } from 'bootstrap-vue'
```

Example Class

```
import { BToast } from 'bootstrap-vue'
class uiUtils
{
        showToast(message : string,title : string){

          let bootStrapToaster = new BToast();

          bootStrapToaster.$bvToast.toast(message, {
              title: title,
              toaster: "b-toaster-top-right",
              solid: true,
              appendToast: false
            })
        }
}
export default new uiUtils();
```

The documentation does show the individual component exports at the bottom of the page and can be found here [Bootstrap Vue Documentation.](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/toast)